# Are these two derivative calculations correct for inverse hyperbolic functions?

Tags: calculus

1. $$ y = \sinh ^{-1} (\tan{x})$$
   $$ y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \tan^2x}} \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \tan{x}$$

$$ = \frac{\sec^2x}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2x}}$$
$$ = \sec{x}$$

Is that right?

2. $$y = \cosh^{-1}\sqrt{x}$$

$$y' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}} \frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{x}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2 \cdot \sqrt{x-1} \sqrt{x}}$$

Anything else I can do here?

Comment: should it be $$\sinh^{-1}(\tan(x))$$?

Comment: :facepalm sorry about that

Comment: the result should be $${\frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}}}$$

Comment: @Jwan622 both your answers are correct

Comment: The first is not correct: it should be $\:|\sec x\mkern1mu|$.

Comment: Who should I listen to? If anyone shows work, I'll give credit!

Comment: why @Bernard? Why should it be the abs value?

Comment: Because $\sqrt{1+\tan ^2x}=\sqrt{\sec^2x}=|\sec x\mkern1mu|$, and $a^2=|a|^2$.